# Filter list based on exact and partial match in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am a newbie to Spark, I have a scenario where I have 2 lists with keywords and the keyword can be a single word or a phrase. I have to filter out the keywords which occur in both the list ( exact match) or even if a substring from list 1 is found in list 2.

For example.

```
PosList= List ( "Abc","Spark is awesome","Scala is powerful")
Neglist= List ("Powerful","Abc","Xyz")

Output = List ("Scala is powerful","Abc")
```

I have achieved the exact match usecase. But struggling with partial match.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are the lists two columns in spark or are you talking about generic scala (outside of spark)?

Comment: So much possibilities here.  First, are your partial matches on word boundaries?  Lists are huge or small?  You could use an inverted index for searching if one of your lists is big.  Otherwise, use cartesian product of your lists and filter the pairs (generated regex, tokenized strings set intersection, simple string contains)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial/Full-match value in one RDD to values in another RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911993/partial-full-match-value-in-one-rdd-to-values-in-another-rdd)

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner in scala, so following solution may not be the best but it will work. Following solution works for exact match of keywords ( exact match for substring too)

```
PosList.filter(x => if(x.split(" ").map(y => Neglist.contains(y)).toList.contains(true)) true else false)
```